# Segmentation fault(core dumped ) error while executing a function which returns an integer pointer

Tags: c

> The program below works fine

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int * p(void);
main()
{
    int *x = p();
    printf("%d", *x);
}
int * p(void)
{
    int x;
    x=10;
    return (&x);
}
```

> However, if I modify the above program like this

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

    int * p(void);
    main()
    {
        int *x = p();
        printf("%d", *x);
    }
    int * p(void)
    {
        int *x;
        *x=10;
        return (x);
    }
```

> On executing the above code a segmentation fault error is thrown.
>
> Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: The program that you say works fine has undefined behavior (it's buggy).  Using an lvalue (in this case, the local variable `x`) after it's lifetime is over is undefined behavior, and if you're lucky it'll crash during testing so you can fix the bug. The fact that it doesn't crash is merely one possible manifestation of that bug.

Comment: you are passing the address of local variable in second case. that will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: try here for some discussion on the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888268/what-happens-when-a-variable-goes-out-of-scope

Comment: @kripanand It's first case that passed local variable address, not second case, which dereferencing uninitialize/unallocated pointer.

Comment: @moeCake you are right .as already answered in the second case there is no address assigned and value is written to some random address and that is causing seg. fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your first program gets a warning and the second program gets an error.

But try this for the second program: use malloc for allocating memory first, then dereference the pointer:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int * p(void);
    main()
    {
         int *x = p();
         printf("%d", *x);
    }
    int * p(void)
    {
       int *x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
       *x=10;
       return (x);
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You are making an error in both, which causes undefined behaviour.

1.

```
int * p(void)
{
    int x;
    x=10;
    return (&x);    <---
}
```

returning an address of a local variable, which stops existing after the return

2.

```
int * p(void)
{
    int *x;
    *x=10;    <---
    return (x);
}
```

dereferencing a pointer that doesn't point to any valid memory

Comment: First one is printing the value 10.

Comment: @user3217911 Undefined behaviour is *undefined*.

Answer (score 0):

Case1: p() returns address of 'x', which gets stored in main's version of int *x, and you can dereference it in the printf to print the value. (Edit: this is also buggy since 'x' in p() is local to p(), and it 'stops existing' once p returns).

Case2: you create *x, and you dereference it before assigning anything to it (x).
Most likely, when you're declaring something on the stack, it will have a random value. The assignment - *x = 10 will try to write the value 10 to whichever address the pointer is pointing to (i.e. the value of x itself). libc can detect an illegal access like this and segfault.